# Facing error after executing Script written in java(Selenium WEbdriver)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have created the two files.
First file in which I have given the browser name and Url.
Second file in which I have given the logical names to the xpath.

I have created the two class correspondingly.
In first class, I have created all the functions.
In second class, iam calling that functions (using inheritance concept[extends]) which are there in the first class.

Uploading all the files.
First File:

```
Browser=Firefox
AppURL=https://www.myntra.com/
```

Second File:

```
Myntra_Search_Xpath=.//*[@id='desktop-header-cnt']/div/div[3]/input
```

First class

```
package Basepack;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class baseclass {
    public static FirefoxDriver driver;

    public static String  getpropValue(String PName) throws IOException{
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        FileInputStream pi=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\workspace\\SeleFirstClass\\src\\Basepack\\Objprop");
        prop.load(pi);
        String Pvalue=prop.getProperty(PName);
        return Pvalue;

    }

    public static String getpathValue(String Pname) throws IOException{
        Properties prop=new Properties();
        FileInputStream pi=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\workspace\\SeleFirstClass\\src\\Basepack\\Objpath");
        prop.load(pi);
        String Pvalue=prop.getProperty(Pname);
        return Pvalue;

    }
    public static void openBrowser(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    }
    public static void navigate(String URLName) throws IOException{
     String path=getpropValue(URLName);
     driver.get(path);
    }
    public static void closeBrowser(){
        driver.close();
    }
    public static void click(String Value) throws IOException{
        String path=getpathValue(Value);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).click();
    }

    public static void type(String path, String Value) throws IOException{
        String Locator=getpathValue(path);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(Locator)).sendKeys(Value);
    }

public static void wait(int i) throws InterruptedException
   {
      Thread.sleep(i*1000);
   }
}
```

Second Class

```
package Basepack;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTestNG extends baseclass{
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforemethod() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        openBrowser();
        navigate("AppURL");
        wait(3000);

    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void aftermethod()
    {
        closeBrowser();
    }

    @Test
    public void invalidlogin1() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        wait(3000);
        type("Flipkart_login_Xpath", "Nike Shoes");
    }

}
```

Following is the error description

```
1494929368178   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:8576
1494929368783   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1494929369821   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < AddonManagerInternal.validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsJavaScmr:i6p6t5  e<r rAodrd:o nrMeasnoaugrecreI:n/t/egrrnea/lm.osdtualretsu/pA(d)d@orneMsaonuargceer:./j/sgmr,e /lmionde 1639: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
ules/AddonManager.jsm:832 < this.AddonManagerPrivate.startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:2773 < amManager.prototype.observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:57
1494929371707   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 53003
JavaScript error: undefined, line 492: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIPrefBranch.getCharPref]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2484: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
May 16, 2017 3:39:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession`enter code here`INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Comment: Can you help me locate the error, I don't see any significant error in the tracelogs. Can you confirm if your actual testing step is getting fired at all or not? Thanks

Comment: please edit your question and format you code properly at least

Comment: @Matthias,  iam new to this,Will take care of this in future ,. Your help would really be appreciated, if you help me in resolving this Issue. Secondly in the second class, instead of 3000(in case of time[wait]) it should be "3".Sorry for this. but still iam facing issue

Comment: it doesn't have to be in the future, you can edit your question right now, just click "edit" under your question, it might attract more answers

Comment: code and text formatting

Comment: When facing such kind of issues, please mention the platform details, your test setup etc. I believe this is due to an existing bug in Marionette driver implementation. Please see issue #613 and #684 on Github.

Comment: @JimHawkins, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding DesiredCapabilities

```
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
   capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```